# gnome-tweak-tools statup applications location

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

Where does gnome-tweak-tool save startup jobs?
I'd like to find where gnome stores its startup jobs and the way it configures its files
I have been searching for hours and i couldn't find anything, please help me.

Comment: I know how to add a new job, what I WANT to know is where these jobs are stored, where the file physically is located

Comment: `~/.config/autostart` should be the place...

Answer (score 2):

Desktop files for the autostart applications are stored in `~/.config/autostart`

```
ls ~/.config/autostart
```

As don_cissti pointed out in the comments.